# Make div take 100% of browser window height

Tags: html, css

how could I make sure that a div takes 100% of the height on every single screen resolution. Like here: https://medium.com/design-playbooks/designing-the-hiring-process-e0b59f3ee53, or here: http://blogs.wsj.com/briefly/2015/01/23/greece-austerity-relief-or-exit-the-short-answer/?mod=e2fb

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to achieve a 100 view height (device height) styling on a div or other elements you can use something like this:

```css
.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
}
div {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-height full-width"></div>
```

This sets the element size using viewport units, where `1 vh` is 1% of the viewport's height and `1 vw` is 1% of the viewport's width. You can also see an example here: https://dominikangerer.com/projects/github/bearded-cyril/ you can see there that I used this to assign `100vh` to the aside on the left side.

Maybe this is relevant for you: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Your `adtime.at` link *looks* like spam. I'm not sure if it is because I have an ad-blocker, but you might want to change the domain name.

Comment: I added an explanation of what `vh` and `vw` means.

Comment: @jpaugh changed to my new domain ;) hope you like this more.

Comment: I do, actually. OTOH, your answer itself was already quite good.

Comment: Don't forget `box-sizing: border-box` otherwise the border will be cropped off if you have one

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `height: 100%;` in your div's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

make your body element 100% hight, then make the div inside 100% hight

Answer (score 0):

You have to style your body to 100% before you can make your div 100%

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

div{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using `100%` (which will take 100% of the body, but the body may be bigger or smaller then the browser actual visible size), I suggest using the units `vh` and `vw`

`100vh` will take 100% of view hight and `100vw` will take 100% of view width. This unit will take 100% of the visible browser screen, no matter what.

**CSS:**

```
body{
   height:100vh;
   width:100vw;
}
```

[Here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design) are some more detailed information about these measurements