# CSS folded corner takes over the whole panel

Tags: html, css

I am having quite a hard time trying to get a folded corner spread over the entire surface of my panel.

I don't want to set up a specific size for the folded corner as I want it to cover the entire surface, whatever the size of the panel (as it would show on mobile, tablet or desktop.

I can't figure out an easy solution to achieve this.

Here is my code :

```css
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.amg-corner-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #46982b;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -ms-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -o-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.amg-corner-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 120px 120px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #46982b #fff;
}

.amg-corner-button_text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -moz-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform-origin: center top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center top center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center top center;
  -o-transform-origin: center top center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default1">

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'>
      <div class='amg-corner-button'></div>
      <span class='amg-corner-button_text'>Text Goes Here</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel body -->

</div>
<!-- panel default -->
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28130491/2968762. Try `height: 96vh;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your css instead.

```
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.amg-corner-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #46982b;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -ms-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -o-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);  
}

.amg-corner-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 120px 120px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #46982b #fff;  
}

.amg-corner-button:hover::before {
  border-width: 0;
}

.amg-corner-button_text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -moz-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform-origin: center top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center top center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center top center;
  -o-transform-origin: center top center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

We did two things. We updated `.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover` and `.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover div` to have a width and height of 100%. This way the panel would take up 100% of the panel.

The second change was adding:

```
.amg-corner-button:hover::before {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Without this we would be left with an extra triangle in panel. We need this triangle to create the green pocket shape we have in the bottom-right hand corner.

Comment: Instead of just giving him a solution, please explain what you solution does.

Comment: Sounds good. Btw if you're into svgs a friend of mine made https://shapeshifter.design/ ;)

Comment: Thank you Joseph. It does take over the whole panel. However when I hover on the text now, the white triangle appears. Any idea why ?

Comment: One more thing, the .amg-corner-button transition does not apply anymore as it now shows directly a rectangle shape instead of "spreading" out as a triangle shape, like it used to do with the original CSS. Consequently, the text inside the corner shows up before the corner actually unfolds completely, instead of letting the text appear gradually.